# Vue.js attribute binding from a list or object

Tags: vuejs2

I'm experimenting with Vue.js (2.3). I'm comfortable with attribute binding manually e.g.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: ['info'],
    computed: {
        type: function() { return info.type },
        classList: function() { return this.info.attributes.classList },
        id: function() { return this.info.attributes.id }
    }
    template: '<component :is="type" :class="classList" :id="id">{{ info.text }}</component>'
})
```

where info =

```
{
    text: 'Some text',
    type: 'h2',
    attributes: {
        classList: 'a string',
        id: 'another-string'
    }
}
```

This would output the following:

```
<h2 class="a string" id="another-string">Some text</h2>
```

But what if I want to bind all the attributes inside my attributes object, regardless of how many or what they are e.g. my info might look like this:

```
{
    text: 'Some text',
    type: 'td'
    attributes: {
        classList: 'a string',
        id: 'another-string',
        colspan: '3',
        rowspan: '2',
        title: 'A string',
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I bind all these attributes without having to list all the possible attributes that might crop up?

Comment: I should add I could modify the attributes property to be a list or object, whatever is easier. E.g. attributes: [{key:"id", value:"a-string"},...]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) accepts an object as it's parameter and binds all the properties to their values.

```
template: '<component :is="type" v-bind="info.attributes"></component>'
```

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks very much, works as you would expect.